# React Native foreach loop

Tags: loops, react-native, foreach

I'm developing a little app in React Native and I am looking for something like a foreach function. I just can't find a foreach loop. Not on StackOverflow and not even in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html). I've found something with 'map', but I don't know if this is what I'm looking for.

With a request to my Server I get multiple objects of users. When I log the result, it looks like this:

```
Object {
    "id": "1",
    "role": "user",
    "username": "user1",
  },
Object {
    "id": "2",
    "role": "admin",
    "username": "user2",
```

I'd like to output this to a list.
In plain PHP I would use a foreach loop for this, but like I said, I can't find a foreach loop for React Native.

How is it possible to loop trought this objects? I know that I could also use a simple for loop, but this would definitly not be my first choice...

**EDIT:**
I saved this value in `this.state.users` with `this.setState({users: responseData.users});`. State is defined in my constructor. I try to access this with `this.state.users.map(id => <Text>{id}</Text>)` but I always get the same error: `null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.users.map')`. Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [for-of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) or any other

Example:

```
// for of
for (let userObject of this.state.users) {
    console.log(userObject.username);
}
// map
this.state.users.map((userData) => {
    console.log(userData.username);
});
```

as per the error you may not have data within `users` state, so you are getting error. If data is proper then above example will work properly

Comment: getting an error like forEach and i tried to solve out but there is another errors are occured so this can't help  but thanks for response

Answer (score 15):

In react, preferred way is `map` method of Array. Example using ES6 arrow function:

```
render() {    
    return (
        <View>    
           {dataList.map(r => <Button>{r}</Button>)}    
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: I get `null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.users.map')`. FYI I've also updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use lodash (npm install lodash) and run the following:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

...

_.each(dataList, function(userObject, key) { console.log(userObject, key); });
```

Comment: This is quite over-engineered.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import BlogContext from "../context/BlogContext";

export default function IndexScreen() {

  const blogPosts = useContext(BlogContext);

  return (
    <View>
      {blogPosts.map((post) => {
        return <Text>{post.title}</Text>;
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
```