# React Native and FlatList : Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am a beginner with react native. I have a variable `this.state.forums` that has this value :

```
{
    "7": {
        "id": 7,
        "wording": "Loisirs, vie sociale et débats"
    },
    "3": {
        "id": 3,
        "wording": "Forums"
    }
}
```

But when I write :

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.forums}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.wording} />}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
/>
```

I have this error :

> Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN

Can you help me ?

And do you know how to assign the key in keyExtractor (not `item.id`) ?

Comment: Are you sure that data you are providing to FlatList exists before FlatList is rendered? Btw for that second question you could do `keyExtractor = {(item, index) => index.toString()}` if that is what you wanted

Comment: Thanks very much for second question.
Yes, and this.state.forums are initialized in constructor `this.state = {forums: []}` before http request.

Comment: What I am thinking, from the first code block you provided. it would look something like this `[{7: ..., 3:...}]`, if that is the case, you need to remove outer `{}` and it would look something like this then: `[7: ..., 3:...]`, tell me if it solved your problem and then I'll write an answer with better explanation

Answer (score 10):

FlatList wants its data in the form of array. You are giving it an object. Get the Object.values and you will be good. Like `data={Object.values(this.state.forums)}` or even better, store the forums in the state as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
// for of
for (let userObject of this.state.forums) {
console.log(userObject.wording); // here you can render your views
}

// map function works for array
this.state.forums.map((userData) => { 
return(
console.log(userData); // render your view
 userData.map((data) => {
  <Text>{data.wording}</Text>
 })
)
});
```

Ref link:- [React Native foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45861099/react-native-foreach-loop)